# HTML <br> code effecting my other code

Tags: html

Hello i am having a issue, i am creating a clan site for my xbox clan, and
here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>MxS Offical Website</title>
<link href="./css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="./css/box.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="nav">
<a href="http://www.youtube.com">xTech</a>
<div class="menu">utubeuser</div>
<div class="menu">utubeuser</div>
<div class="menu">utubeuser</div>
<div class="menu">utubeuser</div>
<div class="menu">utubeuser</div>
</div>
<div id="header"><div style="position:absolute; top:46px; left:50px">
<br><br>

<a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Mxs-Clan/474428962653273?ref=hl" target="_blank" align="right"><img src="http://www.niftybuttons.com/3d/facebook.png"></a><a href="http://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank" align="left"><img src="http://www.niftybuttons.com/3d/youtube.png"></a>

<div id="boxes">
<div id="left">
<div id="box-top-green">Box 1</div>
<div id="box-centro">MxS II Tankz (Leader) 
                    <br>
                    MxS II Tacks (Co Leader)
  <br>
                    MxS II xTech (Tech) 
  <br>
                    MxS II --- 
  <br>
                    MxS II --- 
  <br>
                    MxS II --- 
  <br>
                    MxS II --- 
  <br>
                    MxS II --- 
  <br>
                    MxS II --- 
  <br>
                    MxS II --- 
  <br>
                    MxS II ---</div>
<div id="box-abajo"></div>

<a href="user.php" target="_blank" align="right"><img src="img/acc.png"></a></div>
</div>


<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br>
<div id="right">
<div id="box_top_green">Box 4</div>
<div id="box_centro">Box 100% expandible</div>
<div id="box_abajo"></div>
<div id="box_top_green">Box 5</div>
<div id="box_centro">Box 100% expandible</div>
<div id="box_abajo"></div>
</div>
</div>





</head>
<body>

<br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br>



<div id="footer">Site Made By xTech - Zac<div style="width:300px; float:right;">All rights to there respective owners</div></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Umm the issue is when i put the text in box one (MXS II -- BR MXS II -- BR over and over) the br's move down the other boxes  box 4 & box 5
Is there a way to stop that from happening and i do not want to put the box 1 code under the other code of box 4 and 5 help please.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about web design, not programming. (HTML is not a programming language.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

making so many br will not be supported by the browser..and different browsers have difference in rendering the html code..so make use of CSS code to re-position the boxes..You can use margin,top etc to re-position the div

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to move Box4 and Box5 then put `div overflow` property in Box1, so that when contents in Box1 increase it will show the slider bar. Is this what you need then try with overflow property.

Comment: Deepak biswal would you be able to show be how to fix it by quoting  my code? with the div overflow added to it? if its not to much trouble?

Comment: can you please put your code in jsfiddle and provide the link!